# How to figure out what model of “Intel Graphics HD” my CPU has?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, gaming, intel-graphics

I wanted to download among us game, so I searched what is the system requirements for among us and I saw The cheapest graphics card I can play it on is an `NVIDIA GeForce 510`. So I searched how to check what graphics card I am using? Then I saw two different ways to check it in Windows 7 operating system.

1. I have to right-click on the desktop then I have to select Screen Resolution then advance settings then I will see the name of the graphics card so this is the screenshot:

   [image: The Image]

   At this time I thought I am using Intel HD Graphics 2500 but after using the second way
2. I have to open `dxdiag.exe` then I have to select display tab then I saw this:

   [image: The Image]

   This time I thought I am using Intel HD Graphicss but when I searched on google then I saw there is no graphics card with only `Intel HD Graphics` there has to be a number like 2500, 4000, 2000, etc after the name `Intel HD Graphics`. If that is true then can someone tell me what graphics card I am using on my pc or how to check it? what is the correct way?

---

PS: And here is my device manager window's screenshot:

[image: The Image]

Comment: What version of "Intel Graphics HD" depends on your processor. What model processor do you have?

Comment: If I have to go to ```control panel -> system & security -> system``` then it's ```Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz  3.30 GHz```. I sent the exact same thing, I saw there.  And if it's not the thing you are looking for, then could you please tell me how to check what model processor I have?

Comment: I gave you an answer with a decent screen shot but it was downvoted and deleted.

Comment: You said to use device manager and I said that why my ```Intel(R) Graphics HD``` without any number, but I think the answer was deleted before you saw my comment...

Comment: Its right in your screen shot Intel HD Graphics 2500

Comment: From the intel page for the [i3-3220](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/65693/intel-core-i3-3220-processor-3m-cache-3-30-ghz.html) you apparently do have the Intel® HD Graphics 2500. I've seen many older Intel graphics devices that don't specifically list their version in Device Manager, and even a good few newer systems that don't as well. Updating your graphics driver using https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html might do something, but I don't know what specific requirements your game might have.

Comment: Most likely, Intel HD Graphics 2500 is right. The discrepancy might be caused by an old driver. See [Downloads for Intel® HD Graphics 2500](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81501/Intel-HD-Graphics-2500).

Comment: Is there any way to get Intel HD Graphics 4000? And is ```Intel Graphics HD 2500``` better than/more powerful than ```NVidia GeForce 510```?

Comment: John's answer was "deleted by post author", for what it's worth.

Comment: "Is there any way to get Intel HD Graphics 4000? " Upgrade to a processor that has it.

Comment: @music2myear - For whats it worth it was deleted despite being the correct answer

Comment: @rafid100 - You would have to replace your entire system.  Due to the age of your hardware, you will be unable to play Among Us. The i3-3220 is nearly a decade old since it was released in 2012.